# How to split multiple dictionaries in row into new rows using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with multiple dictionaries in a list in the Rules column.

```
SetID      SetName             Rules
    0         Standard_1        [{'RulesID': '10', 'RuleName': 'name_abc'}, {'RulesID': '11', 'RuleName': 'name_xyz'}]   
    1         Standard_2        [{'RulesID': '12', 'RuleName': 'name_arg'}]
```

The desired output is:

```
SetID      SetName             RulesID        RuleName         
    0         Standard_1        10            name_abc
    0         Standard_1        11            name_xyz 
    1         Standard_2        12            name_arg
```

It might be possible that there are more than two dictionaries inside of the list.

I am thinking about a pop, explode or pivot function to build the dataframe but I have no clue how to start.

Each advice will be very appreciated!

EDIT: To build the dataframe you can use the follwing dataframe constructor:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[0, 'Standard_1', [{'RulesID': '10', 'RuleName': 'name_abc'}, {'RulesID': '11', 'RuleName': 'name_xyz'}]], [1, 'Standard_2', [{'RulesID': '12', 'RuleName': 'name_arg'}]]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SetID', 'SetName', 'Rules'])
```

Comment: What is `print(type(df['Rules'].iloc[0]))`?

Comment: It is <class 'list'>

Comment: Can you provide the input as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: I added the constructor in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `explode`:

```
tmp = df.explode('Rules').reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([tmp, pd.json_normalize(tmp['Rules'])], axis=1).drop('Rules', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   SetID     SetName RulesID  RuleName
0      0  Standard_1      10  name_abc
1      0  Standard_1      11  name_xyz
2      1  Standard_2      12  name_arg
```

One-liner version of the above:

```
df.explode('Rules').reset_index(drop=True).pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([x, pd.json_normalize(x['Rules'])], axis=1)).drop('Rules', axis=1)
```

Comment: Great. It's fascinating how you solved this in a one-liner. Pandas and Python are very powerful.

Comment: @richardec  hm, I don't know if I find the right words to describe what I'm trying to ask, but while trying to find a solution I thought it could work somehow with `pd.explode` and `pd.json_normalize` but I tried to use `apply` (and failed). Never heard of `pipe`, why is it the better (or maybe only?) choice here?

Comment: @Rabinzel `pipe` simply enables me to make a one-liner out of a solution which otherwise would have to be multi-line. The `pipe` solution is actually identical to the two-line solution.

Comment: oh, yes, now I see the other solution aswell. Nice job. But isn't the one-liner also possible with apply ? from my little understanding of apply, used with lambda it executes code row by row, like we need to do here.

Comment: @Rabinzel Yes, it's certainly possible to use `apply` here, but `explode` will be more efficient. I use `pd.concat` because `json_normalize` returns a whole new dataframe.

Comment: @richardec. Thanks. I think a mistake slipped in while editing your answer. In your one-liner you still use tmp instead of `x`. Maybe you want to correct that.